# Eslint: disable operator `in`

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there any way to tell `eslint` that using operator `in` is not allowed?

I mean:

```js
console.log(1 in [1]);
```

Comment: I don't think there's a built in rule for it, but you can most definitely make one, you can probably do it in 5 lines or less.

Comment: Here's an example of how they implemented the `no-new` rule: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/no-new.js. Your rule will likely be very similar.

Comment: Thanks @MadaraUchiha, but i am looking for a built in rule.

Comment: I'm looking for a flying horse. That doesn't mean that one exists, I'm afraid.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the `in` operator?

Comment: Everything is ok, but some possible errors can be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## disallow specified syntax (no-restricted-syntax)

> For instance, you might decide to disallow the use of try-catch or
>   class, or you might decide to disallow the use of the **in operator**.

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax